# How can I read out a text file?

Tags: linux, audio, text, mediaplayer, text-to-speech

I want to convert text in file a.txt to sound & play it using APLAY. any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/).

```
text2wave myfile.txt | aplay
```

It is widely available in distributions and provides different voices.

Comment: Piping no longer works with text2wave [https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=861211] yet using festival its possible to do `festival --tts file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

**`espeak`** can read aloud in several languages. English is default, but you can use the option `-v sv` for Swedish and corresponding voices for other languages. See `man espeak` for more details. For example, change the speed, if you think `espeak` speaks too fast.

You can install `espeak` from the repository Universe,

```
sudo apt install espeak
```

and it can read from a string, a file or from standard input (you can pipe into it), for example

```
espeak 'Hello World'
espeak < /etc/hostname
date '+It is %H %M'| espeak
```

So it should work for you to run

```
espeak < a.txt
```

See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098171/the-speak-text-feature-in-okular-is-not-working-how-do-i-get-it-to-work/1098404#1098404).

Comment: or espeak-ng of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

`flite` : http://www.festvox.org/flite/

```
echo 'Hello world' | flite
```